# Android Gradle compile project's specific flavor

Tags: android, gradle

I am having troubles with product flavors, my project contains library named **Core** and application named i.e. **App**.

In build.gradle file of my **App** module I am compiling this library project like this:

```
 dependencies {
   compile project(':Core')
 }
```

This is working fine but issue comes when I want to introduce specific product flavors in both my library project "**Core**" and my application module "**App**".

**In Core buid.gradle file** I have defined one product flavor :

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {

    }
}

sourceSets.flavor1 {

        java {
            exclude '**/SomeFilePath/*'
        }
}
```

Now once I've added this new flavor to my Core library, I want to change build.gradle in my **App** application module so that I can compile only this productFlavor named flavor1 from my **Core** project.

I tried something like this, but it fails with error **"No configuration with named "flavor1Release" found."**

```
dependencies {
  compile project(path: ':Core', configuration: 'flavor1Release')
}
```

Just to sum it all, I want to have multiple flavors in my **App** application module and each of this flavors would compile different flavor from my **Core** library project. This way every flavor from my **App** module would have different files included in build from this **Core** library.

Does anyone know how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are explicitly providing the configuration to compile your project. But you don't  need to do that because "Android Studio" already provide that option

> To work on files from a particular flavor, click on Build Variants on
>   the left of the IDE window and select the flavor you want to modify in
>   the Build Variants panel,

[image]

For product flavors you need to specify following things:

```
productFlavors {
        demo {
            applicationId "com.buildsystemexample.app.demo"
            versionName "1.0-demo"
        }
        full {
            applicationId "com.buildsystemexample.app.full"
            versionName "1.0-full"
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried without this configuration also but I can't compile it.
The moment I added product flavor "flavor1" to my Core project I could't compile it anymore from my App application module.

I had this in my App module dependencies { compile project(':Core') } 

With this I could compile normally my Core project but when I added this flavor to Core build.gradle I couldn't compile it from App module anymore.

productFlavors { flavor1 {} }

What am I missing ? The only change in build.gradle is this line with new flavor ? Once I remove this flavor1 it can compile Core project again?

Comment: I added this but I am getting this error now : Error:Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set to 'com.example.Core' in flavor 'flavor1'.

This Core project is library and I haven't defined anywhere this applicationId, just In this flavor where you pointed out that is missing. 

Do you know what is the issue ?

Comment: I read somewhere that android libraries doesn't support flavors, is this true?